# Some time API request takes more time then usual

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have APIs hosted on AWS, and I have written below code in my iOS app to request data using those APIs. Now some time it takes 7 - 10 seconds to get response back, and sometime it takes 1 - 2 seconds.

```
 let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url,
                                              cachePolicy: .useProtocolCachePolicy,
                                              timeoutInterval: 30)
            request.httpMethod = methodName
            request.allHTTPHeaderFields = (isAuthHeaderRequired ? headers as? [String : String] : nil)

            if let dictParam = parameters, JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(dictParam) {
                let postData: Data? = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dictParam, options: [])
                let strParam = String(data: postData ?? Data(), encoding: .utf8)

                request.httpBody = postData
            }
            else {
                print("Parameters : No Input Parameters")
            }

            let session = URLSession.shared
            dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in

               // Handle response and proceed further 

            })

    dataTask.resume()
```

I have also verified that there is no issue of token expiration.

I want to figure out is there anything wrong with AWS setup which leads to this problem of delay in some cases only or there is anything needed from app side.

Comment: This could be because of a number of reasons. Slow mobile data speed/signal, overloaded backend server, API doing too much etc etc etc. We cannot possibly provide an answer based on the information you have provided. You should add monitoring to your backend services, test from other devices, test on wifi, test your api, test your network requests with something like Postman (chrome app).

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of information missing here and I think I can only provide a general answer.

I see that you've tagged this question with "aws-lambda". If you're using lambdas to support your APIs, I suggest you take a read up on cold starts.

TO summarize, your running lambda instance will terminate every once in a while and this will sometimes result in your "first" request initiating a fresh start-up of your lambda. To validate this, you could take a look at Cloudwatch logs.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried hitting a different API to check that they come back in the same time? You can use [json-gen](http://json-gen.com) to create a simple API response that you can call from your app to check how long it takes.

Also you mentioned you're using AWS, if you're using lambda it makes sense that it takes different lengths of time for the response to come through, that's how lambda works because it's server-less it will need to "spin up" for the first response.